# Loop though object for jsx

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

I am have a problem displaying the images as a list. was wondering why?
I don't have any errors so i am not sure how to solve this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const friends = [
  {
    title: "Yummmmmmm",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-monkeyweirdo.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "Hey Guys!  Wait Up!",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-earnestfrog.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "Yikes",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-alpaca.jpg"
  }
];

// New component class starts here:
```

I used a map function to loop though the above array of object datatypes.
i injected to extract the key's values.

```
 class Friend extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let flist = friends.map((friend, i) =>{
      <li key={"friend_" + i}>
        <h1>{friend[i].title}</h1>
        <img src={friend[i].src} alt={friend[i].title} />
      </li>
    })
    return (<div>
                    <ul>{flist}</ul>
                </div>);
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Friend />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Which problem? Be more specific and if possible post the complete file.

Comment: Define "problem".

Comment: you are not returning anything from map body. by default it returns undefined.

Comment: You're missing a return.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map) function. Try:

```
class Friend extends React.Component{
  render(){
    let flist = friends.map((friend) => (
      <li key={friend.title}>
        <h1>{friend.title}</h1>
        <img src={friend.src} alt={friend.title} />
      </li>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{flist}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You also don't need to select the object like: `friend[i]`, because you are already iterating over every element of the list.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there's nothing wrong with how the OP is using map, just how the arrow function is defined.

Comment: Actually, you are right. He is not using it in a wrong way.